# The pullback line bundle restricted on the exceptional divisor is trivial

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, complex-manifolds, blowup

Let $\sigma:\hat X\to X$ be the blow up of a point $x\in X$, denote the exceptional divisors $\sigma^{-1}(x)$ by $E$. $L\to X$ is a line bundle. Then we have a pullback line bundle $\sigma^*L\to\hat X$. Then why is the restriction of $\sigma^*L|_E\to E$ trivial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pulling back $L$ along $\sigma$ and then pulling back the result along the inclusion $i:E\to\hat X$. That's the same as pulling $L$ back along the composite map $\sigma\circ i$, and that composite map is the constant map $E\to X$ sending all of $E$ to the point $x$. And pulling any bundle back along a constant map always gives you a trivial bundle.

Comment: If we consider $\sigma$ is the blow up of two points ($x_1,x_2$), and we consider the restriction on $E_1\cup E_2$, where $E_i=\sigma^{-1}(x_i)$ is also trivial, is that because this new bundle is the disjoint union of two trivial bundle that you proved?

Comment: I assume, because of the tags, that you're talking about holomorphic sections of a complex bundle, not, say, merely smooth sections of a $C^\infty$ bundle.  In this situation, I wouldn't expect the sections of a trivial line bundle over a disconnected but compact space to be constant. They'd be locally constant; so they'd be  constant on each connected component.